# How to get cell value from selected row (QTableView)?

Tags: c++, qt, qtableview

I have a `QTableView` and I need to the get value (string) from the first cell of the selected row (any cell on the row could be selected). But I need this value *only if exactly one row was selected*.

I thought - I need to get index of the selected row and then get the value of the first сell on that line, but I couldn't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
myTableView->selectionModel()->currentIndex().row()
```

Will give you the index of the currently selected row.  From there you should have enough information to look up the row/column pair in your model.

Also, `QItemSelectionModel::selectedRows()` will let you know how many rows are selected.

Comment: I am able to get the row index, but how to get the value at the first column for example ?

Comment: An old question by @Suda.nese but for anyone else who needs to get the value: `QModelIndex index=myTableView->selectionModel()->currentIndex();` to get the index, then `QVariant value=index.sibling(index.row(),index.column()).data();` will get the value of the clicked cell.

Comment: Extremely helpful, can confirm that this works on PyQt5 as well

Answer (score 10):

Python Code will look like :

```
    self.tableView.clicked.connect(self.on_Click)
```

When User Click on Table Cell the on_Click() method is invoked

```
    def on_Click(self):
        # #selected cell value.
        index=(self.tableView.selectionModel().currentIndex())
        # print(index)
        value=index.sibling(index.row(),index.column()).data()
        print(value)
```

Explanation.

"value" contains the cell value of the selected cell.

```
       index.row() # gives current selected row.
       index.column() # gives current selected column.
       index.sibling(index.row(),index.column()).data() # will return cell data
```

Comment: Your answer pointed me in the right direction and helped me solve an issue i was having for months getting tool tips to work from my qtableview qsqltablemodel index.

the only mod i had to do was to use

cause i had tried this
`index.sibling(index.row(),index.column()).data()`

with the column set to 5 but it did not work
`index.sibling(index.row(),index.column(5)).data()`

So i ended up using this which worked to get the value from the same index row but column5 of the selection.
`index.siblingAtColumn(5).data()`

Comment: Works like a charm..!

Comment: index.siblingAtColumn(5).data() worked for me on PyQt6 also!